# Do i need to check the data type before inserting an excel sheet data in to an sql table through C#.net code?

Tags: sql, excel, import

I need to export records from an excel sheet in to an sql table. Do i need to validate the type of data in each column before insertion? Does the SQL table treats the coming data to its type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the data type is checked for `INSERT` and `UPDATE` and you will get a data type mismatch error if the new data cannot be coerced to the column's data type.

Note that determining the columns data type is not straightforward; if you have mixed data in the same column you could use this to your advantage by forcing the column to text (may require altering local machine registry values). See [Mixed Data Types](http://www.dicks-blog.com/archives/2004/06/03/external-data-mixed-data-types/).

Comment: Actually my requirement is to ensure each column within the excel matches with its corresponding column in the sql table. For that purpose i need to check each column for the predefined type and prevent it from inserting to the table. Haow can i implement this through c#.net code?